# Rounding down value after division, datatable datacolumn

Tags: c#, datacolumn

I want to round down column  values after division aplied:

```
 DataColumn maxSpend = new DataColumn();
    maxSpend.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
    maxSpend.Expression = string.Format("{0:0.00} / price", this.maxSpend);
```

Its possible somehow to use Math.floor() in column expression or  are there  other solutions for this ?

Comment: Are you trying to divide this.maxSpend by price here string.Format("{0:0.00} / price", this.maxSpend);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET functions are not allowed in DataColumn-Expressions. The easiest would be to do it in the first place in the the dbms(if you're using any).

For example in [SQL-Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx): `SELECT FLOOR(MaxSpend/Price)AS MaxSpend ...`.

The other way is looping through the DataRows. For example:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
    double price    = row.Field<double>("price");
    row["maxSpend"] = Math.Floor(this.maxSpend / price);
}
```